# Safety of using an object's lifetime as setter

Tags: c++, scope

I made a 'scoped setter' that automatically assigns a value to a variable, usually POD, when it goes out of scope. I'm using it mainly for keeping track of whether the execution is currently in a certain scope.

```
template<typename T>
struct FScopedSetter
{
    FScopedSetter(T& InObject, T InbOutOfScopeValue)
    {
        Object = &InObject;
        bOutOfScopeValue = InbOutOfScopeValue;
    }
    virtual ~FScopedSetter()
    {
        *Object = bOutOfScopeValue;
    }

    T* Object;
    T bOutOfScopeValue;
};

// Example:
bool bInTaskA = false;
void TaskA()
{
    bInTaskA = true;
    FScopedSetter<bool> Setter(bInTaskA, false);

    // ..
}
```

This should be safer when later I decide to put an extra return statement in TaskA, but forget to add bInTaskA = false before it.

My question is: Is this correct and will it (always) work correctly, at least when using PODs, assuming I name the FScopedSetter object? I'm a bit worried the compiler might decide it can end the lifetime of the setter early because it is unused?

Thanks!

Comment: It's fine as far as I can tell, although I'd use some general implementation of the scope guard pattern instead of a custom-built one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, a named setter object will not get destroyed before its time which is at the end of scope. It will get destroyed as usual: in reverse order of construction.

However, there are a few minor issues with the code posted. For one, the destructor of `FScopedSetter` doesn't have to be virtual as there's no inheritance here.

And `T::operator=(const T&)` must never throw (better declared `noexcept`), otherwise destructor of your scoped assigner class may throw. If your code is targeted at C++11, it would be even better to move `bOutOfScopeValue` to `*Object`:

```
FScopedSetter(T& InObject, T InbOutOfScopeValue)
 : Object(&InObject)
 , bOutOfScopeValue(InbOutOfScopeValue)
{
}
~FScopedSetter()
{
    static_assert(noexcept(*Object = std::move(bOutOfScopeValue)),
        "Move assignment of your data type may throw. Make sure it doesn't.");
    *Object = std::move(bOutOfScopeValue);
}
```

And accessing `*Object` might require synchronization, depending on whether 'tasks' have something to do with 'threads'.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the idea seems fine.
However it is better to use `shared_ptr<>` to be sure that the dependent object does not go out of scope too soon which would crash your program.

```
template<typename T>
struct FScopedSetter
{
    FScopedSetter(std::shared_ptr<T> InObject, T InbOutOfScopeValue)
        : Object(InObject), bOutOfScopeValue(InbOutOfScopeValue) {}
    virtual ~FScopedSetter()
    {
        *Object = bOutOfScopeValue;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> Object;
    T bOutOfScopeValue;
};

// Example:
auto bInTaskA = make_shared<bool>(false);
void TaskA()
{
    *bInTaskA = true;
    FScopedSetter<bool> Setter(bInTaskA, false);
    // ..
}
```

You can also use `shared_ptr` directly instead of your class just checking if it is not NULL. However your way allows to pass some additional information in `bOutOfScopeValue` thus making it better. Also please check for NULL where appropriate in the above code.